# Can I send a blank alert message for APNS/GCM?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

APNS Ex:

```
{
  "content":
  {
    "aps":
    {
      "alert" : "",
      "badge" : 37,
      "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
  },
}
```

GCM Ex:

```
{
  "content":
  {
    "registration_ids":
    [
      "abc...xyz",
      "012...789",
      "~!@...*_+"
    ],
    "time_to_live":100,
    "data":
    {
      "message":""
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a blank message. The question is what purpuse that blank message would serve.

In APNS, you can simply ommit the `alert` property from the payload, and no alert will be displayed (only the badge will be updated and the sound played).

In GCM, there is no special purpose to the `message` property. You can include whatever properties you wish inside the `data` dictionary, and it's up to you to decide what to do with those properties in your app.

Comment: Maybe for dry-run testing, and to check how fast you can push to all devices (like 100k devices).